# Извлечение подстроки

Tags: c#

Необходимо извлечь определённую часть строки. Пример:

```
"FIO eq Ivan Ivanov" => "Ivan Ivanov"
"Id eq 5" => "5"
"FIO cs a" => "a"
"Count eq 587" => "587"
```

Подстрока должна извлекаться, начиная со второго пробела (не включительно). Как это можно реализовать? Может использовать какие-нибудь регулярные выражения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var testString = "Count eq 587";
            var result = String.Join(" ", testString.Split(' ').Skip(2));
            //или
            var result = String.Join(" ", Regex.Split(testString, @"\s+").Skip(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно есть более оптимальные варианты, в данном случае разбивает строку на массив подстрок где разделитель пробел(один или несколько, для второго варианта), пропускает первые 2 подстроки и оставшиеся объединяет этим же пробелом. Правда количество этих самых пробелов теряется, если их больше 2х, для второго варианта.

Comment: Очень элегантное решение, спасибо большое